# Getting CD drive letter in VB.NET

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, drives, drive-letter

I am using the following code to get a list of the letters for each drive on my computer. I want to get the drive letter of the CD drive from this list.  How do I check it?

The code I am using to get list is as below:

In the `Form.Load` event:

```
    cmbDrives.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Dim sDrive As String, sDrives() As String

    sDrives = ListAllDrives()

    For Each sDrive In sDrives

    Next
    cmbDrives.Items.AddRange(ListAllDrives())
```

.
.
.

```
Public Function ListAllDrives() As String()
    Dim arDrives() As String
    arDrives = IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives()
    Return arDrives
End Function
```

Comment: So, the code you've shown works to enumerate all the drive letters, and you're asking how to determine which one is the CD-ROM drive? What do you propose to do in cases where the computer has *multiple* CD drives (such as a CD-RW and a DVD)?

Comment: yes sir, that is the issue.  May be it can put the letters of all these dirves into a listbox??????  But how to determine the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested, and returns the correct results on my computer:

```
Dim cdDrives = From d In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives() _
                Where d.DriveType = IO.DriveType.CDRom _
                Select d

For Each drive In cdDrives
    Console.WriteLine(drive.Name)
Next
```

Assumes 3.5, of course, since it's using LINQ. To populate the list box, change the Console.WriteLine to ListBox.Items.Add.

Comment: Hrmm, looks like I *did* miss it. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each drive In DriveInfo.GetDrives()

   If drive.DriveType = DriveType.CDRom Then
       MessageBox.Show(drive.ToString())
   Else 
       MessageBox.Show("Not the cd or dvd rom" & " " & drive.ToString())
   End If

Next
```